# Is it possible to use two different versions of JasperServer with the same website?

Tags: jboss, jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

**Summary:** is it possible to serve reports created with 2 different versions of iReports in the same web front end?

**Background:**
I have inherited a large number of (still-functioning) reports written using iReport 2.0.1 (migrating them all to a later version is probably not an option, unless anyone knows of a brilliant/quick solution). I want to increase our ongoing reporting functionality by creating new reports in a later version of iReport (at least 3.7.1, but ideally 4.x).

**System Setup:**
JBossAS 4.2.1 on *Server A* (with apache 2.x) with JasperReports 3.5.7 also running on *Server A*, responsible for reports 1-100

**Question**: 
Is it reasonable/feasible to install JasperReports 4.x on *Server B* (knowing that it requires a different environment than earlier versions, & so cannot also run on *Server A*) and have (future) reports 101 and up, created using e.g. iReport 4.x, served JBoss on *Server A* but parsed by the JasperReports server running on *Server B*?

(It may not be relevant, but our database is Postgres 8.1.3)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool in the Jasper distribtion that can update your JRXML files to the latest version of the schema. If you're comfortable with Ant scripts try it out:

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/antupdate/index.html

I used it sucessfully when we upgraded from Jasper 1.3 to 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work.

Reports working in JR 3.5.7 should also work in JR 4.2.1 (or even 4.5.0). Backwards compatibility is very good. (But it's not magically good... so you'll need to test.) You can set iReport to save to older .jrxml versions. And you would need to be careful to not use features that were introduced after 3.5.7.

You should at least test the brilliant/quick solution of just running the 100 reports in the later version of JasperReports Server. You might be pleasantly surprised to find that they just work.